# IE7-8 don't seem to see jQuery corner plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using malsup's jQuery Corners plugin in order to have rounded corners in every browser. So far - it worked good for me. But now - it doesn't. It simply doesn't - I don't know how to describe it.

Maybe you know other way to have rounded corners on both old IEs and modern browsers?

HTML:

```
<nav id="mainMenu" class="container_24">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Two ›</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Three ›</a></li>
        <li class="search">
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search ›">
            </form>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">‹ Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (LESS):

```
nav#mainMenu {
    margin-top: -9px;
    background: #fafafa;
    height: 62px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e2e2e2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.25);

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        li:last-child {
            a {
                border: 0;
            }
        }

        li {
            float: left;

            a, input {
                display: block;
                font: bold 12px/62px "Source Sans Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #4b4b4b;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 0 20px;
                border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
            }
            a:hover, input:focus {
                border-bottom: 3px solid #cc624a;
                text-decoration: none;
                outline: 0
            }

            form {
                input {
                    border: 0;
                    border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
                    height: 62px;
                    background: transparent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('nav#mainMenu').corner('5px');
$('nav#mainMenu ul li:first-child a').corner('5px bl');
$('nav#mainMenu ul li:last-child a').corner('5px br');
```

My [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/c48hS/).

Comment: fiddle would help... plugin was written before IE8 even existed or was quite new

Comment: updated with fiddle and code.

Comment: my personal opinion is that if browser doesn't support corner radius users are used to it and it is better to use css only for those browsers that do support it, instead of adding unnecessary js

Comment: @charlietfl - it's certainly a good way, but if a design is focused on rounded corners, forcing a lot of users (everyone using WinXP) to use much worse version isn't fair. A lot of people doesn't have the freedom of installing third party software on their computers at work etc., so they have to stick with WinXP and IE8.

Comment: right .... but it's not about condemning them...they are used to not seeing CSS3 on those machines is my point. Many likely already know that their browsers are inferior if they work on one machine and use a better one at home. A lot depends on the type of site also. A heavy branding site would certainly have different perspective than a more utilitarian one

Comment: Maybe. But still, I think that couple more kilobytes (today, 10Mbps is almost a standard) won't harm you, and it may be helpful for those, who doesn't use modern browsers. PIE is ~80KB, which isn't that much.

Comment: I did play with it for a bit yesterday only on your page in IE8... no idea whay it's not working. Not throwing errors either. There are a couple of other corner plugins could try. I know malsup from years in jQuery forums...his plugins are typically really solid. His cycle plugin has a huge use base

Comment: one suggestion...  use modernizr or similar to test browser support and only apply corners in js for browsers that don't allow radius. Use CSS otherwise. Also I think there are some CSS3 shims that might even make cornvers work similar to Pie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read, jQuery Corners plugin has issues like this, with backgrounds and borders. So, instead of this, I used [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) and it works great.